# Android: last object added to the list overrides all others

Tags: java, android, list, android-listview

I am entering the objects in the list and noticed that the last added this overriding all others on the list, the following code snippets.

```
private List<NoticiaListView> getNoticias() {
        try {
            List<Noticia> lNoticiaParseObject = null;
            List<NoticiaListView> lNoticiaListView = new ArrayList<NoticiaListView>();
            NoticiaListView nListView = new NoticiaListView();

            ParseQuery<Noticia> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Noticia.class);
            query.whereEqualTo("ativo", true);
            query.include("imagem");
            lNoticiaParseObject = query.fromLocalDatastore().find();

            if (!lNoticiaParseObject.isEmpty()) {
                for (Noticia noticia : lNoticiaParseObject) {
                    nListView.setImagem(noticia.getImagemByteArray((Midia) noticia.getParseObject("imagem")));
                    nListView.setTitulo(noticia.getTitulo());
                    nListView.setConteudo(noticia.getConteudo());
                    nListView.setLink(noticia.getLink());
                    nListView.setCreatedAt(noticia.getCreatedAt().getTime());

                    lNoticiaListView.add(nListView);
                }
                return lNoticiaListView;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

classe NoticiaListView:

```
public class NoticiaListView {
    private String titulo;
    private String conteudo;
    private String link;
    private long createdAt;
    private byte[] imagemBytes;

    public NoticiaListView() {
        /*this.titulo = titulo;
        this.conteudo = conteudo;
        this.link = link;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.imagemBytes = imagemBytes;*/
    }

    //region GETTERS

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getConteudo() {
        return conteudo;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public long getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public byte[] getImagem() {
        return imagemBytes;
    }

    //endregion

    //region SETTERS

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public void setConteudo(String conteudo) {
        this.conteudo = conteudo;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(long createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public void setImagem(byte[] imagem) {
        this.imagemBytes = imagem;
    }
    //endregion
}
```

Class Noticia:

```
public class Noticia extends ParseObject {

    public Noticia() {
        /*deixar vazio*/
    }

    //region GETTERS
    public ParseACL getParseACL(){
        return getParseACL();
    }

    /*public String getObjectId() {
        return getObjectId();
    }*/

    /*public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return getCreatedAt();
    }*/

/*    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return getUpdatedAt();
    }*/

    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return getBoolean("ativo");
    }

    public String getConteudo() {
        return getString("conteudo");
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return getString("link");
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return getString("titulo");
    }

    public byte[] getImagemByteArray(Midia midia) {
        byte[] imageData = new byte[0];
        try {
            imageData = midia.getParseFile("arquivo").getData();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageData;
    }
    //endregion

    //region SETTERS
    public void setACL(ParseACL acl){
        put("ACL", acl);
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        put("createdAt", createdAt);
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        put("updatedAt", updatedAt);
    }

    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        put("ativo", ativo);
    }

    public void setConteudo(String conteudo) {
        put("conteudo", conteudo);
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        put("link", link);
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        put("titulo", titulo);
    }

    public void setImagem(ParseRelation<Midia> imagem) {
        put("imagem", imagem);
    }
    //endregion
}
```

How to solve this problem by using lists? I hope not need to change for collections only for one reason thereof. I read another question that the possible problem could be "static fields", but in my code does not have any static field.

Answer (score 3):

please change your code as below. because you have just created object one time and It should be create multiple times depend on your list size. you should create object in for loop.

```
private List<NoticiaListView> getNoticias() {
    try {
        List<Noticia> lNoticiaParseObject = null;
        List<NoticiaListView> lNoticiaListView = new ArrayList<NoticiaListView>();


        ParseQuery<Noticia> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Noticia.class);
        query.whereEqualTo("ativo", true);
        query.include("imagem");
        lNoticiaParseObject = query.fromLocalDatastore().find();

        if (!lNoticiaParseObject.isEmpty()) {
            for (Noticia noticia : lNoticiaParseObject) {
                NoticiaListView nListView = new NoticiaListView();///  change here.
                nListView.setImagem(noticia.getImagemByteArray((Midia) noticia.getParseObject("imagem")));
                nListView.setTitulo(noticia.getTitulo());
                nListView.setConteudo(noticia.getConteudo());
                nListView.setLink(noticia.getLink());
                nListView.setCreatedAt(noticia.getCreatedAt().getTime());

                lNoticiaListView.add(nListView);
            }
            return lNoticiaListView;
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Android: last object added to the list overrides all others

Create `nListView` object of `NoticiaListView` class inside `for-each` loop to add new object in ArrayList:

```
 for (Noticia noticia : lNoticiaParseObject) {
     // create object here
     NoticiaListView nListView = new NoticiaListView(); 
     // ... your code here..      
     lNoticiaListView.add(nListView);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Re initialize the object `nListView`

```
 for (Noticia noticia : lNoticiaParseObject) {
                        nListView.setImagem(noticia.getImagemByteArray((Midia) noticia.getParseObject("imagem")));
                        nListView.setTitulo(noticia.getTitulo());
                        nListView.setConteudo(noticia.getConteudo());
                        nListView.setLink(noticia.getLink());
                        nListView.setCreatedAt(noticia.getCreatedAt().getTime());

                        lNoticiaListView.add(nListView);
                        nListView = new NoticiaListView();
                    }
```

Hope this will help you..